# How can I make a .bat file run automatically when an alert box pops up?

Tags: command-line, windows-10, batch-file

Sometimes POP Peeper suddenly does not work on my computer. Whenever it happens, an alert box will pop up, and the box's PID in Task Manager is 244. The solution is to restart POP Peeper. I know how to use a .bat file to restart a program, but don't know how to make the file run automatically when the alert box pops up.

Can anyone teach me how to do that? 
The following is the alert box in question.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the process ID is always 244 ? It would be hard to chase around the process ID as its not constant only unique

Comment: I will check whether the PID is still 244 next time when the alert pops up again.  What should I do if it is not?

Comment: If all you want to do is "restart POP Peeper when the message box shown above appears", I know a easy solution using vbscript.

Comment: The alert popped up again just a few minutes ago, and I confirm that the PID is not constant. Please teach me how to  "restart POP Peeper when the message box shown above appears" using vbscript.

Comment: What is the process name of that popup box ?

Comment: There are many process names in Task Manager. How can I find out which one refers to the alert box? The above-mentioned PID refers to POPPeeper.exe instead of the box. That's my mistake.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32655/discussion-between-the-it-guy-you-dont-like-and-matthew-wai).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script below should do what you wanted i.e. *close the popup when it comes & then restart another process*

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    i = x 
    Do While i = x
        Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
            ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'notepad.exe'")
            '("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'Name of Your process you are waiting for to start'")

    If colProcesses.Count = 0 Then
        'It does not exist do nothing
    Else
        For Each objProcess in colProcesses
            'this will close the process you were watching, as soon as it starts
            objProcess.Terminate()

                'Closing the process you want to restart
                Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
                 ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'winword.exe'")
                 '("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'name of the process you want to terminate'")
                For Each objProcess2 in colProcesses
                 objProcess2.Terminate()
                Next

            Dim objShell
            Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

            objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe""")
            'objShell.Run("""process or application you want to start""")
            Set objShell = Nothing

        Next
    End If

Loop
```

Comment: For example, I want `C:\Windows\notepad.exe` to be restarted when `C:\Windows\write.exe` starts. What should be the script?

Comment: @MatthewWai Use tool like **Notepad++** and set the language to **VB**. The line that starts with **'** is a comment and shows green. It has instructions for you.

Comment: I had replaced `Name of Your process you are waiting for to start` with `notepad.exe`, replaced `name of the process you want to terminate` with `wordpad.exe`, and replaced `process or application you want to start` with `C:\Windows\write.exe`, and had started `wordpad.exe`, but nothing happened when I ran the script and started `notepad.exe`. Why?

Comment: did you remove the comment ?

Comment: www.dropbox.com/s/f298naflls3d33x/Script.bat?dl=0  Please tell me whether I did it correctly.

Comment: @MatthewWai, Three things **1** : Script above is not batch but VBScript so you need to save it as **.vbs** **2**.: **write.exe** is actually **wordpad.exe** **3** : Location of notepad.exe is C:\Windows\System32\

Comment: Get it from here http://pastebin.com/dSF45a5f

Comment: Assuming that I want only `C:\Windows\testing.bat` to run when `wordpad.exe` appears, what should the script be?